# Rails routes duplicate params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, duplicates

I got this route

```
post 'webhooks/sendgrid', to: 'webhooks#sendgrid'
```

And send this body raw json { "email": "brioansdkasd" }
But in my params come this

```
Parameters: {"email"=>"brioansdkasd", "webhook"=>{"email"=>"brioansdkasd"}}
```

Somebody can tell me how to send it only out of "webhook"? Thanks!

Comment: Send it as `{ webhook: { email: '...' } }`

Comment: can you please provide some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s because in wrap_parameters.rb yo can configure that and I've configured to json calls.